# Python File Conversion using subprocess

Tags: python

I'm trying to use an external program which converts a file to another specific file type.

I've been trying to find out how to perform this in python, I can successfully execute the commands in the command line but when I'm trying to use Python I'm having some problems.

This is my current code I am using but I get an error in the terminal saying:

> unrecognized arguments: > test.xml

In python, I am stating 'python' the script 'file_convert.py' and the target file to be converted.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("python", "file_convert.py", "targetfile.txt", ">", "test.xml"])
```

Comment: Why don't you import the module?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to redirect standard output. It is not the same as passing another argument to the program, you need to use pipes

Comment: Why don't you just remove `">"`, and use `"test.xml"` as second argument? Then, in your python script you can write to it.